# No Module Named Zeep - Python

Tags: python, linux, api, soap, zeep

I am trying to run the command:

```
python -m zeep [wsdl url]
```

to inspect the wsdl file. However, I keep getting the error

> /usr/bin/python: No module named zeep

I have already run

```
pip install zeep
```

and it successfully installed. However, this command keeps failing.

I am running these commands on a remote (ssh) server with python 2.7.

Answer (score 4):

First check the python version you have if it's python 3 
run

```
python3 -m pip install zeep
```

then run the command

```
python3 -m zeep <wsdl url>
```

if you chose to work with python2 then change the 3 to 2 or 2.7

Comment: That is the command I am trying. I have already installed zeep, re-running 'pip install zeep' gives me a number of lines with the command 'Requirement already satisfied'

Comment: my version is python 2.7

Comment: then use pip2 and re-run the command nd tell me what happened?

Comment: ok, run the command 'python' so u get to the python terminal nd then type 'import zeep'

Comment: That is not working either - same error (No module named zeep)

Comment: that means it's not there, the pip u used didnt install it in the python u r using

Comment: Sorry for being so clueless, but what is the fix for that?

Comment: what i usually do is to install the package with all the pips in my system, pip2 pip3 pip3.*, i type pip nd then click tab twice to see all the pip versions i have nd install the package with all the pip versions

Answer (score 2):

the proper command should be

```
python -m zeep <wsdl url>
```

if it doesn't work make sure that

```
pip install zeep
```

run successfully

Comment: That is the command I am trying. I have already installed zeep, re-running 'pip install zeep' gives me a number of lines with the command 'Requirement already satisfied'

Comment: Try 
python -m pip install zeep --user
This will ensure that zeep is installed using the pip which is associated to your python interpreter

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
/usr/bin/pip install zeep
```

Reason:

run `which pip`, and check the realpath of `pip`

If the realpath is not `/usr/bin/pip`

You might installed module zeep in other python library